# Python doesn't run flask

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, pip

I'm running Kubuntu 20.10 and trying to run the flask-script out of "Head first Python", page 203:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')         #Funktionsdekorator
def hello() -> str:
    return "Hello world from Flask!"

app.run
```

But when I try to run it in the shell with

```
python3 hello_flask.py
```

there is no response. It just takes me back to the promp. I also can't access the website at 127.0.0.1. When I do pip list, it says that Flask 1.1.2 is installed. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: See [Flask quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `()` on `app.run()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `app.run()` not `app.run` because with parentheses, you're calling the function.

Comment: The arrow defines a type annotation for the return type, useful for static analysis with ```mypy```

Comment: @Joac Didn't know that, as you can tell I am somewhat a beginner. Thanks!